# Create a Laravel project with only the resources needed to make an API

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use Laravel to create an API only. But when I create the laravel project using:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myApi
```

I get a lot of files like `package.json` or some Webpack configuration. These files are very useful to create some front-end interfaces, but I don't really need that since I only want my Laravel project to interact with a database and answer to some API calls.

Is there a way to initially create a Laravel project without all the front-end stuff? Something like:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myApi --api
```

Comment: You can use Lumen instead

Comment: @RishiRaut Oh well thats look fabulous for my purpose thanks ;)

Comment: Why is actually my question downvoted ? Is it really of topic or opinion-base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) instead

> Lumen is the perfect solution for building Laravel based
>   micro-services and blazing fast APIs. In fact, it's one of the fastest
>   micro-frameworks available. It has never been easier to write
>   stunningly fast services to support your Laravel applications.

Or

You may use [Slim micro framework](http://www.slimframework.com/)

> Slim is a PHP micro framework that helps you quickly write simple yet
>   powerful web applications and APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I didn't know Slim before ;)